# How to be good at angles and trigonometry

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry, soft-question, triangles

I am Computer Science Engineer and loved algebra side of Mathematics. But when it comes to trigonometry and angles and triangles, I do not understand anything since college time. And till now also whenever I get chance to avoid sin/cos/tan I consciously (because of fear) avoid that.

Can you please suggest easiest way to learn trigonometry.

Kindly do not suggest lengthy books. They will only discourage me at their best.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry) is a great place to start.

Comment: It's really not my intention to sound mean or anything, but how does an engineer get by without knowing trig?

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE Computer Science has practically nothing to do with trig.. And it is not I do not know at all. Just not good at it. I have cleared papers having trigs.

Comment: What kind of trigonometric problems you have? Solving geometric problems? Handling trigonometric identities? And in what context? Do you have to use it in school or in your work? If the latter, there are ways to solve both geometry problems and handling trigonometric identities without using trigonometry.

Comment: @RGB I need to solve work problem. And it is coming at various places so I cannot avoid it. Recent example is to calculate center of tingle and it's angle, we need it for GSM. Though I use Google to solve our problem. Still lot of gray matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practice is the only way to master any subject in Mathematics. You can look up some high school/college level books. I personally liked "Trigonometry" by S.L. Loney.

However, there are many other references available. Practice as many problems as you can.

Comment: Lastly had to agree. Practice is the only way.. thanx for answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider both of the following,

- [***Trigonometry by Gelfand***](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817639144) - This text will not bore you... Gelfand's Great! ~\$25
- [***Schaum's Outline of Trigonometry***](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071795359) - Schaum's Outlines are generally quite good. ~\$10

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share my experience learning trig with you. First, let me assure that I have no special aptitude for mathematics. But it only took me about 8 weeks to absolutely master the pre-calculus aspects of trig. I just worked hard, studying several hours every day from a great trig text by Charles P McKeague  ([http://www.amazon.com/Trigonometry-Charles-P-McKeague/dp/0495108359/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1374726391&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495108359)). (Used copies this text will probably run you $20 or so.) I worked every problem in the text; I worked many of the problems sets twice or even three times. I invested quite a bit of time learning the material in those 8 weeks, but when it was over, I had a solid foundation to build on when I went on to study calc.

You can do it! The bad news is learning trig requires lucubration; the good news is that's basically all it requires. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. Conclusion is I must practice.